# Use javascript function to output Jade tags

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'd like know if I can use javascript to write Jade tags into a Jade template?

for example:

```
  function write_p(text) {
    return p.paragraph text;
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a mixin with jade.

```
mixin pgraph(text)
    p.paragraph= text

+pgraph("Hello World")
```

This will output

```
<p class="paragraph">Hello World</p>
```